# How to set up a script such that every time there is a new modification on google sheet, my script will be triggered and some action will be performed

Tags: python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a script such that every time there is a modification on google sheet, my python script will be triggered and it will do a simple action, such as sending me or someone else a SMS message notifying that the sheet has been modified.

So far I am able to connect google sheet API to automatically download the entire sheet. However, I am not sure the best way to receive an alert and consequentially trigger my script to perform the series of actions. I am thinking of potentially using Flask but not sure how exactly to do it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/

Answer (score 1):

Your issue can be solved by **triggering the execution of your Python script through Google Apps Script**.

You can use an installable trigger which will monitor each change in your Spreadsheet. Afterwards, the Python script you have can be hosted on the cloud or in a private server and you can trigger its execution by using the `UrlFetchApp()` function which will fire an HTTP request to an endpoint of your choice.

- **The** `runScript()` **function:**

```
function runScript() {
  var params = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': {
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload': '{"name":"Name"}'
    }
  };
  var pyScript = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://YOUR_REGION-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME', params);
}
```

This function is used to trigger the execution of your Python script.

- **The** `onChangeTrigger()` **function:**

```
function onChangeTrigger() {
  runScript();
  var recipient = "RECIPIENT_ADDRESS";
  var subject = "MAIL_SUBJECT";
  var body = "MAIL_CONTENT";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

This function is the installable trigger used to monitor the changes in the Spreadsheet and calling the `runScript()`.

Moreover, the installable trigger should have the **event type** selected to **On change**, like this:

[image]

Furthermore, I suggest you check the following links since they might be of help:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app);
- [GCP HTTP Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http).

Answer (score 0):

**Sends an email on every edit**

Note this function sends you an email on any edit to any page/sheet.

```
function sendmessageonEdit(e) {
  var body=Utilities.formatString('Spreadsheet: %s\nSheet: %s\nRange: %s',e.source.getName(),e.range.getSheet().getName(),e.range.getA1Notation());
  MailApp.sendEmail('your email','Your Spreadsheet has been modified', body)

}
```

Requires an installable trigger.

```
function createSendMessageOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //Check for triggers with same name
  if(!isTrigger('sendmessageonEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendmessageonEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create()
  }
}
```

This function just checks to make sure that there isn't already a trigger with the same name.

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

[ScriptApp.newTrigger()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: is it possible to something linked this with my python script rather than doing it in the script editor ?

Comment: You could setup a webapp so that you could get a log of the most recent events and instead of sending emails the script could log them for you.